# Can't display data type in c++ using Atom?

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I'm trying to display datatypes of variables in c++ using Atom text editor. The below code snippet works in MS visual studio but in atom it doesn't display the type or any other print statement after the `typeid(i).name()` line.

From what I could understand rtti flag isn't enabled in atom and I can't seem to figure out a way to enable it. I keep coming across `-fno-rtti` to disable rtti  in compiler command line  options but nothing to enable it.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <typeinfo>      

int main() {
    int i=0;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    std::cout << "  i is: " << typeid(i).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by displaying a data type in Atom? Atom is a *text editor*, it should not display anything from your program.

Comment: you didn't flush std::cout, so it won't display anything. use std::flush or std::endl, to display your data

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when I compile and run using the gpp-compiler package in atom I expect an output for the std::cout<< i; statement.

Comment: @basslo I tried both std::flush and std::endl and still getting the same result.